# Formula for the period length of the simplest continued fraction of the square root of n

Tags: radicals, continued-fractions

The period length of the simplest continued fraction of the square root of any natural number n is always finite. Is there a formula for the period length of the simplest continued fraction of the square root of n?

Comment: The first question doesn't make sense since, in general, real numbers don't have periodic continued fractions

Comment: @jjagmath I edited it

Comment: no formula. There are upper bounds,  as the count  of Gauss-Lagrange reduced   indefinite binary forms has  upper bounds   based on the discriminant